# Why does my MySQL database tables only exist on my Workbench?

Tags: php, mysql, missing-data

I am developing my first php-MySQL system, but have a minimum of database experience. I have successfully created a schema with aproximately 10 tables, and the testings have so far worked fine.

My problems started when i created a dump of the database, as copy for my laptop, so I could continue to test new web pages and new queries even when I am not at home, and still use a localhosted database.

I have successfully imported the dump, and created the schema in my workbench, and it is visible from the command-line prompt "show databases".

However, both my web application, and the command-line prompts are unable to locate the underlying tables. THe problem is at least not directly in my php-code, as it works perfectly on another computer, with another, but assumably identical localhosted database. I have researched the matter online for what feels like a decade, but without any relevant results.

Command-line prompts are able to find tables from every other schema, like the sakila examples. I have tried to compare the two's settings, but they all seem to be identical, for instance they are both InnoDB.

I realise that I am not giving enough information for a direct solution here, but I would greatly appreciate if anyone could hguide me to finding the right questions to ask, so I can solve this matter, and get on with my php-learning.

(SOLVED)

I discovered that the list of open tables had references to an additional Schema. I thereafter realised that I had installed the XAMPP bundle server before I installed MySQL Workbench. In other words, i already had an existing database, with all of the regular examples included in another instance, which were running on port 3306. It also happpened to have an identical, but empty scheme, of the name that I tried to access.

My newly added SQL installation was ported to 3307, and so I am now able to access it. THis issue was just one of several issues I have been able to work around, but they have all been caused by the same mistake. Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Comment: Can you confirm user and permission are identical on the two databases?

Comment: Are there any tables inside the imported database? Try from the commandline `use dbName; show tables;` Maybe more important. Did you get any errors while importing?